# I am trying to connect my R script and Node JS

Tags: html, r, node.js

But this error has been coming up lately:
C:\Users\vidyush.bakshi\Desktop\node-karteek\node_modules\r-script\index.js:48   if (child.stderr) throw child.stderr;

The source code is as follows:

```
R.prototype.callSync = function(_opts) {
var opts = _opts || {};
this.options.env.input = JSON.stringify([this.d, this.path, opts]);
var child = child_process.spawnSync("Rscript", this.args, this.options);
if (child.stderr) throw child.stderr;
return(JSON.parse(child.stdout));
};
```

Can anyone help me with this please..

Comment: You're throwing the `stderr` you're receiving from the `child process`. I think that is what is causing issues for you.